# Loopback console script does not exit

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm writing a Loopback script that is supposed to be called by cron.

In order to obtain the `app` object, I do

```
var app = require('./server/server');

# Script logic
console.log('done');
```

However, the script does not exit once it finishes execution. How do I make it exit?

Reference: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects

Comment: Is ./server/server starting an http server, but failing to close it?

Comment: What is `./server/server` doing? If it's creating an object to `.listen()`, the script won't exit immediately.

Comment: I'm not too sure, the idea is so that I could get access to `app` object and eventually get access to the models, etc.

Comment: You can, but, you should make sure that the .listen is only called if the app is not being included as a module of something else so that the app will be booted, but won't be listening for http requests.

Comment: For the `require` of `server.js`, it's based on http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects at the **Working with data source objects** section.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I probably should have phrased my question to be: How do I get loopback-boot not to listen.

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app/blob/master/server/server.js#L42

Comment: @KevinB That's what I tried too. Even without calling `app.start()`, it's still not exiting. Am I missing something?

Comment: there must be something else still listening. that should have been enough to take care of the http server keeping it from stopping.

Comment: You could force it to exit with process.exit()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78815/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-uzyn).

Comment: Still haven't found a proper solution. Thanks to @KevinB http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78815/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-uzyn the current workaround is inserting `process.exit()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found out the cause of this issue.

The problem is due to database connection (in my case, mongodb via [loopback-connector-mongodb](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb)) is still connected.

To disconnect database connection, and subsequently exiting the console script

```
var app = require('./server/server');
app.dataSources.DATASOURCENAME.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

In some places I've read that the issue is the http server preventing the script from shutting down.

I ended up with a module which does not even start an http server, I named it `loopback-init.js` and I usually import it from migrations and scripts (the important part is the custom callback passed to `boot()`):

```
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const loopback = require('loopback');
const boot = require('loopback-boot');
const logger = require('logger');
const app = loopback();

boot(app, __dirname + '/../server', err => {
    if (err) throw err;

    logger.debug('Loopback initialized.');
    app.start = function() {
        app.close = function(cb) {
            app.removeAllListeners('started');
            app.removeAllListeners('loaded');
            if (cb) cb();
        };
    };
});

const autoMigrate = Promise.promisify(
    app.dataSources.db.automigrate,
    {context: app.dataSources.db}
);

app.autoMigrate = autoMigrate;
module.exports = app;
```

and my [db-migrate](https://github.com/db-migrate/node-db-migrate) scripts look like this:

```
'use strict';

var dbm;
var type;
var seed;

/**
  * We receive the dbmigrate dependency from dbmigrate initially.
  * This enables us to not have to rely on NODE_PATH.
  */
exports.setup = function(options, seedLink) {
  dbm = options.dbmigrate;
  type = dbm.dataType;
  seed = seedLink;
};

exports.up = function(db) {
    const lb = require('loopback-init');
    return lb.autoMigrate('Item')
        .then(lb.close, lb.close);
};

exports.down = function(db) {
    return db.dropTable('item');
};

exports._meta = {
  "version": 1
};
```